# sql sum some column when all other columns match

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2, sum

I have the following SQL temp table which is a result of an SQL query

[image]

I am trying to SUM columns `numitems` and `ignoreditems` where all the other columns match

I tried something like the following query:

```
SELECT 
    catalogid, 
    sum(numitems), sum(ignoreditesm) 
FROM ##temporderstable 
GROUP BY 
    catalogid, supplierid, cname, cprice, cstock, ccode, minstock, pother4
```

I can't seem to get it to work

I get an error

> *numitems doesn't belong to the table*

although I can see it when I run the command

```
select * from ##temporderstable
```

Comment: Do you get an error? (and if so: **what** error?) Or do you just not get the expected data? Then please tell us what you get, and what you actually wanted to get instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to add aliases:

```
SELECT 
    T.catalogid, 
    sum(T.numitems) as numitems, 
    sum(T.ignoreditesm)  as ignoreditesm
FROM ##temporderstable T
GROUP BY 
    T.catalogid, T.supplierid, T.cname, T.cprice, 
    T.cstock, T.ccode, T.minstock, T.pother4
```